# Cant connect spring application to postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, eclipse, jpa

Yesterday I could run my application, connect it to the database and even use it, today I just cant. I'm using springboot, eclipse, swagger and postgresql. Already tried restarting postgresql on my machine and nothing.

Error message:

```
10:04:58.744 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@7708de08

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2021-12-03 10:04:59.003  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] com.crud.CrudApplication                 : Starting CrudApplication using Java 17.0.1 on GON170102162 with PID 4672 (C:\Users\murillo.jorge\eclipse-workspace\CRUD\target\classes started by murillo.jorge in C:\Users\murillo.jorge\eclipse-workspace\CRUD)
2021-12-03 10:04:59.004  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] com.crud.CrudApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-03 10:04:59.037  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-12-03 10:04:59.037  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-12-03 10:04:59.595  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-03 10:04:59.627  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 27 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-12-03 10:05:00.011  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-03 10:05:00.020  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-03 10:05:00.020  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-12-03 10:05:00.102  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-03 10:05:00.103  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1065 ms
2021-12-03 10:05:00.144  WARN 4672 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2021-12-03 10:05:00.146  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-03 10:05:00.157  INFO 4672 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-03 10:05:00.168 ERROR 4672 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Clientes
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


#spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATASOURCE_URL}
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true


spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

My project structure

```
|   .classpath
|   .gitignore
|   .project
|   HELP.md
|   mvnw
|   mvnw.cmd
|   pom.xml
|   test.txt
|   
+---.mvn
|   \---wrapper
|           maven-wrapper.jar
|           maven-wrapper.properties
|           MavenWrapperDownloader.java
|           
+---.settings
|       org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
|       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
|       org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
|       org.springframework.ide.eclipse.prefs
|       
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   |   \---com
|   |   |       \---crud
|   |   |           |   CrudApplication.java
|   |   |           |   
|   |   |           +---controller
|   |   |           |       ClienteController.java
|   |   |           |       
|   |   |           +---model
|   |   |           |       Cliente.java
|   |   |           |       
|   |   |           \---repository
|   |   |                   ClienteRepository.java
|   |   |                   
|   |   \---resources
|   |       |   application.properties
|   |       |   
|   |       +---static
|   |       \---templates
|   \---test
|       \---java
|           \---com
|               \---crud
|                       CrudApplicationTests.java
|                       
\---target
    +---classes
    |   |   application.properties
    |   |   
    |   \---com
    |       \---crud
    |           |   CrudApplication.class
    |           |   
    |           +---controller
    |           |       ClienteController.class
    |           |       
    |           +---model
    |           |       Cliente.class
    |           |       
    |           \---repository
    |                   ClienteRepository.class
    |                   
    \---test-classes
        \---com
            \---crud
                    CrudApplicationTests.class
```

Edit: put my project structure and error message inside code tags

Comment: please add the logging as is with code tags, not as quotes as now it it totally unreadable. Your `application.properties` is probably in the wrong location, hence not read, hence the error.

Comment: It is inside src/main/resources

Comment: Again please add the logging as is, the current one is totally unreadable (and unsalvagable I did a reformatting attempt but that is impossible). Show your project structure as well. There must be something preventing it from being read.

Comment: Just added my error message to code tags and put my project structure on my original post.

Comment: Try mvn spring-boot:run and see what happens

Comment: The question is very General